Euler's mesh characteristic and watertightness properety of a 3d STL surface mesh [SOLVED}
I need to determine if a 3D volume triangular surface mesh (STL) represents a watertight volume or not. If I use python trimesh module it tells me if it is or it is not, but it does not tell why.
It is also computing the Euler characteristic number but I am not sure if it is not 2 simply means that the surface mesh is not watertight.
My question  is can I use the Euler characteristic = 2 as a criterion to detect watertightness?
Thank you for reading!

Every triangulation (watertight or not) has an Euler characteristic. Can you please edit the question to clarify what you're asking? (An if and only if algorithm or criterion for watertightness...?)

Thank you so much for this correction.

Briefly, no. To check watertightness it's necessary to establish

The triangulation is manifold, and
Has empty boundary.

Checking whether the Euler characteristic is $2$ is neither necessary nor sufficient:

A connected, watertight triangulation has Euler characteristic $2$ if and only if it is homeomorphic to a sphere.
A triangulation with Euler characteristic $2$ need not be watertight, e.g., two disjoint triangles.


Many thanks! This is a very complete and thorough answer, unfortunately I do not have enough credit to accept the answer! best wishes -Zuheyr
